# ¿Cómo accionar un evento de un botón desde otra página?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy en ASP .Net MVC y mediante Jquery estoy tratando de hacer un direccionamiento a una página y luego en dicha página ejecutar o hacer clic en un botón, de esta manera:

```
let solicitarCredito = $('#iniciarSesion');
solicitarCredito.on('click', solicitarCredito, function (event) {
    window.location.replace("/Home/Index");
    $('#solicitarPrestamo').submit().trigger('click');
});
```

El evento satisfactoramiente me redirecciona a la página, pero no me ejecuta el método `trigger` para hacer clic en el botón, ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este inconveniente?.

El botón `$('#iniciarSesion')` pertenece a un menú, que es una vista parcial, por lo cual este aparece en distintas páginas, es decir puedo estar en la página contactos y el botón `$('#iniciarSesion')` está disponible pero el evento `$('#solicitarPrestamo')` activa un submit en la página hacia un controlador que recibe unos parámetros de la página index, pero si el usuario se encuentra en otra página como contacto, `$('#solicitarPrestamo')` no estará disponible para ejecutar el `submit` opciones como `Ajax` las debo descartar debido a que el requerimiento es que no se pueden ver datos en `URL` espero esté más claro el proceso y si hay más opciones de solución.

```
<li>
   <a class="btn btn-info" id="iniciarSesion">Crear Cuenta</a>
</li>
```

El botón submit está activado mediante un `@using (Html.BeginForm)`

```
<button class="botonGrande" type="submit" id="solicitarPrestamo">!Solicitar Prestamo¡</button>
```

dicho botón solo se encuentra en la vista `index`, entonces lo que quiero hacer es que aunque no estén el vista `index` al dar al botón `$('#iniciarSesion')` que está en el menú que es vista parcial llegue a ejecutar el evento `submit`
del botón `$('#solicitarPrestamo')` gracias.

Comment: lo que quieres hacer no se puede, pero existe un truco, pasas por parametro en la URL tu JavaScript en el evento `onload` verificas si viene el parametro y si es correcto aplicas el click

Comment: debes re evaluar tu logica mejor explica que deseas hacer, lo que tienes y lo que esperas que haga el codigo y el porque del mismo hay otro truquito que seria enviado en id por url y capturando el evento focus sobre este para para desabilitarlo pero mejor explica lo que necesitas!

Comment: Ya hice algunas explicaciones extra espero sean de ayuda, gracias por su interés en mi problema.